# What programming language or technology to use for defining a rule set on JSON parsing?

Tags: json, validation, parsing, grammar, rules

I'm facing the following scenario. I am currently writing a validation mechanism on JSON-files, to verify that several constraints are met. **For this task, I am wondering, which might be the best tool to be used and I'd be happy for any fitting suggestions.**

Now some of you might want to mention here, that the usage of a JSON-schema validator might be the thing I'm searching for, but I personally think it does not match my use case.

Let me give you an example:

```
{ 
    "document" : {
         "Type" : "A",
         "Action" : [ "ActionA",
                      "ActionB",
                      "ActionC"
                    ]
    } 
}
```

For the upper, simplified document, I would like to define rules for validation, which produce errors or hints, in case they are not met.

Rules could (in an abstract manner) be described as something like this:

- if document has type "A" and "ActionB" in Actions then throw error
- if document has type "B" then throw error
- if document has no type then throw error
- if document has type "C" and "ActionC" is not in Actions then throw error

Such a "black-listing" approach for such a rule set would be a preferred solution to me, but also a "white-list"-based approach could fit the situation quite well. The sample rules I have described here can also be more complex and span across multiple levels in the JSON-hierarchy.

As far as I'm informed, JSON schema validation is not capable of completing the described task, as it merely validates that the syntax on a JSON file is correct. But I'll gladly admit my failure, in case I was wrong.

I have constructed an architecture around that parsing mechanism based on python and initially wanted to also implement the described validation with python. But on the second look, I had the feeling that there might be better fitting tools for this task.
Tools like **Yacc** (in conjunction with lex) came in to my mind, as the whole situation tends to the necessity to define a grammar on JSON-files, which executes the rule set I'd like to implement. But unfortunately I am not very familiar with such tools and therefore was unable to evaluate, whether it would be the right choice.

**So, to repeat my question. I would like to know, which tool or programming language would make a good fit on my problem in a "clean" manner?** (By the term "clean" I just mean that the tool should basically be destined for the desired purpose and does not need a bunch of work-arounds to get it done. Because otherwise any tool would fit the purpose)

Comment: The programming language you personally feel most comfortable coding in, provided it has a good JSON library (which you should use for the syntactic parse). Coding your own json parser in order to code semantic coherency rules would be a waste of time (as well as error prone).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an approach using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).  The basic idea is to express your checks as jq functions.

For example if you have a file `bad.json` with a bad document

```
{"document":{"Type":"A","Action":["ActionA","ActionB","ActionC"]}}
```

and a file `good.json` with a good document

```
{"document":{"Type":"Good"}}
```

this command

```
jq -Mnr '
   def case1: if (.document.Type == "A") and (.document.Action|contains(["ActionB"])) then "case 1" else empty end;
   def case2: if .document.Type == "B" then "case 2" else empty end;
   def case3: if .document.Type == null then "case 3" else empty end;
   def case4: if (.document.Type == "A") and (.document.Action|contains(["ActionD"])|not) then "case 4" else empty end;
   def status:
       first(case1, case2, case3, case4, "ok")
   ;

     inputs
   | "\(input_filename): \(status)"

' bad.json good.json
```

produces

```
bad.json: case 1
good.json: ok
```